# Remove characters in csv file powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, scripting

[image]I'm running a ps1 script as gpo in all the computers from the domain, this script will bring certain details of each computer such as hostname, manufacturer, OS, etc and save it to a csv file.

I'm having an issue since the script runs just fine, however for some reason there are like empty spaces between some lines.

For example:

ThinkCentre M73;"PC-L314-PER03";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"
;;;
To be filled by O.E.M.;"PC-L312-PER02";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"
ThinkCentre M700;"PC-L111-GES";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"
;;;
ThinkCentre M70q;"PC-L367-REC01";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"

; it's the delimiter I have set. Since I have already gathered the information needed, I'm importing the CSV to PS so that I can clean this empty spaces and export it back to a CSV file so that I can upload this to A DB.

Any ideas how to get rid of the spaces between lines?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I've been googling for a solution but haven't been able to find something that fits my case.

Comment: What spaces? Your pic does not show space, but empty rows with your delimiter, then just don't print those out. Just use a ```-replace``` to remove the consecutive delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment. Here's what I mean.

```
Clear-Host
@'
ThinkCentre M73;"PC-L314-PER03";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" 
;;; 
To be filled by O.E.M.;"PC-L312-PER02";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" 
ThinkCentre M700;"PC-L111-GES";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" 
;;; 
ThinkCentre M70q;"PC-L367-REC01";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"
'@ -replace ';+\s+'
# Results
<#
ThinkCentre M73;"PC-L314-PER03";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" 
To be filled by O.E.M.;"PC-L312-PER02";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" 
ThinkCentre M700;"PC-L111-GES";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro" 
ThinkCentre M70q;"PC-L367-REC01";"LENOVO";"Microsoft Windows 10 Pro"
#>
```

Comment: This did it.  Thank you so much. I appreciate taking your time to answer. Thank you again!!